# Unescape html entities from JSON in Django templates

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-templates, html-entities

I'm getting the response from server that is escaped:

```
'item':'&lt;b&gt; Some Data &lt;/b&gt;'
```

I pass such data to template useing  `item= json.loads(response)`

By default django templates (in Google App Engine) escapes it further,
so its double escaped in results.
I can use `safe` to remove one level of escaping like:

```
{{item|safe}}
```

How do i turn entities to their corresponding signs?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**Warning** - THIS IS NOT A RECOMMENDED SOLUTION. You should be using autoescaping instead (check [Rafael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2387061/rafael-zottesso)).

Following should do the job.
`response.replace('&amp;', '&').replace('&lt;', '<').replace('&gt;', '>')`

**Update -**
After suggestion by [Jan Schär](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5127629/jan-sch%c3%a4r), you should rather use the following :
`response.replace('&lt;', '<').replace('&gt;', '>').replace('&amp;', '&')`

Because, if `response` is `&amp;gt;`, it would result in `>` instead of the correct `&gt;`. You should resolve `&amp;` in the last.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this:

```
{% autoescape off %}
  {{ your_text_var }}
{% endautoescape %}
```